# z-index not working on safari

Tags: css, z-index

I stopped at safari with a z-index bug and can't move forward, tried almost all possible ways, since my code has not giving me enough freedom to edit because the code has used several other pages.

I'm coming on the issue, my site in mobile view all browsers except in safari main menu goes just below the heading tag that has z-index and positioned to get a cut off feeling from the header image here you can see...

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here you can see the css

Header --------- section

```
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bg-1-34-8.jpg") repeat scroll center top / cover !important;
    height: 335.5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    z-index: unset !important;
}
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
}
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10010;
}
```

Items Heading -----------

```
.footer-press-title {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
}
.fusion-imageframe {
    z-index: 1;
}
.fusion-imageframe {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to remove it entirely or are you just moving it somewhere else?

Comment: actually I want to show the menu over the heading ITEMS

Comment: Well, your current z-index puts it above everything. try changing the z-index to a negative value.

Comment: if I change z-index -1 for whole heading area .fusion-header-wrapper it will    disable and I can't see anything from header section, that is header bg, menu logo. And I tried to change .fusion-imageframe it goes down the header section which cause the ITEMS goes below the header BG so it breaks and not looking like in the first image I posted above :(

Comment: Can you include the relevant `html` in your question, please?

Comment: have you tried removing it altogether via `display: none` or hiding it via `visibility: hidden` whenever the menu is active, meaning `.class-name-of-menu:active{ display: none }`

Comment: Why are you using the same class .fusion-header-wrapper and then overwriting the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the positioning `absolute !important;` in .fusion-header-wrapper class is affecting the stacking context.

Remove the `absolute !important;`

To read more about Stacking Context see the Example section in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context